# uninitialized constant Google::Cloud::Vision::ImageAnnotator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-vision

Running this example
 https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/face-tutorial?hl=zh-tw

by rails on 'google-cloud-vision', '~> 0.31.0'

got the error

> uninitialized constant Google::Cloud::Vision::ImageAnnotator

here's the code

```
require "google/cloud/vision"


project_id = 'xxxxxx'


vision = Google::Cloud::Vision.new project: project_id


image_annotator = Google::Cloud::Vision::ImageAnnotator.new
```

Comment: don't know why I got this error 

'uninitialized constant Google::Cloud::Vision::ImageAnnotator'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the error was caused because I haven't use the latest version of gcloud-vision(0.32.x)

the way to do what I wanna do in gcloud-vision(0.31.0) is

```
image = vision.image "path/to/face.jpg"

face = image.face
```

instead of using  class

> Google::Cloud::Vision::ImageAnnotator

Answer (score 0):

Solution is Here --- just install this gem 'google-cloud-vision', '~> 0.32.0'